# Por que ter medo de votos negativos em série?

Tags: debate, votos, serial-voting

Vi, em algumas discussões sobre votos negativos, algumas pessoas dizendo que não explicam o voto negativo que dão por medo de retaliação, na forma de votos negativos em série.

Como estou do lado da turma que acha que os votos negativos estão, sim, sendo mal utilizados e causando uma má experiência para os usuários, especialmente os novatos, isso me preocupa.

Afinal, se votos negativos em série são revertidos automaticamente pelo sistema, por que esse medo? Seria falta de informação a respeito? Falta de confiança no algoritmo?

Comment: Nem tudo é revertido, somente se forem dados em serie. Porém, a pessoa pode muito bem não sair negativando de uma vez, mas cada vez que ver uma postagem sua, porque não vai com sua cara. E o sistema, por mais que ele seja realmente eficiente e é bastante, não reverte sempre tudo, somente se encontrar o padrão programado., Então, pode muito bem ocorrer de alguns votos não serem revertidos(já aconteceu comigo). Mas isso não é o maior problema, e sim o fato de alguns membros verem o negativo como um ataque pessoal, e outros usarem para esta finalidade. Pelo menos é o que eu acho a respeito.

Comment: Se não são em série, não vai ser uma coisa com pouquíssimo impacto? Cada voto negativo diminui apenas 2 de reputação. E, além disso, se você dá um voto negativo sem explicação, a pessoa do outro lado pode também sentir que foi um ataque pessoal, e não dá pra dizer que é sem razão. Afinal, ninguém perde tempo escrevendo uma pergunta ou resposta sem achar que está boa.

Comment: Pablo veja o final do meu comentário, o voto em serie é o menor dos problemas...

Comment: Eu li seu comentário todo. Veja a parte da minha resposta depois de "E, além disso".

Comment: Quando é usuário novo, eu ainda acabo justificando(não digo -1, mas informo o que tem de errado). Agora com usuário já estabelecido, isso nem sempre é bem aceito.

Comment: @diegof existem assassinos em série que matam uma pessoa por ano (pelo menos em alguns filmes que eu vi), os votos assim como as mortes não precisam ser um em cima do outro para poderem ser considerados "em série" ;-)

Comment: @DiegoF Eu acredito que o problema do voto negativo está mesmo nos usuários novos. Como usuário mais experiente, quando recebo um voto negativo sem motivo aparente e não recebo resposta após questionar, simplesmente vejo como birra. Como usuário novato, a sensação inevitável é a de "não sou bem-vindo aqui". Não dá pra medir quantos bons contribuidores em potencial a gente pode já ter perdido pra essa sensação.

Comment: @Math Sua analogia seria válida se um voto negativo para alguém experiente aqui retirasse toda a reputação recebida na vida (ou uma quantidade exorbitante). Não é o caso. Para quem se preocupa com esses votos negativos de vez em quando, não consigo não pensar nessa pergunta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away

Comment: @Pablo admito que só negativo quando percebo que o usuário é teimoso ou faz desdém da sua boa vontade em ajudar(seja novato ou mais estabelecido), e não melhora o conteúdo. Na grande maioria das vezes, um comentário já da um toque e nem precisa de negativar. Agora se o tempo em que você avisa até quando ele visualiza e altera acaba gerando seu negativo, já entra em outro problema que está sendo [discutido aqui no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4863/notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-votos-negativos)

Comment: @Math o problema nem é o negativo ou a série em si mais, eu fico mais incomodado é por imaginar que estou criando uma inimizade por causa de um ponto negativo que não tem valor monetário, não pode ser trocado  por dots e nem por viagens :p kkk falando sério, é chato mesmo imaginar isso.

Comment: A analogia é meio ruim sim, mas o q eu quero dizer na verdade é que o sistema trata os casos mais escancarados já os moderadores podem agir em casos mais específicos. Um voto negativo por ano é claro que não se encaixaria nisso.

Comment: @DiegoF Eu sigo a mesma ideia. Se eu não tenho tempo para explicar e ninguém mais explicou, deixo como está ou apenas sinalizo (se for o caso). Quando à sensação, realmente, é ruim e não tem como tirar da pessoa o direito de se sentir assim. A quem tem esse receio, acho que vale mais a pena sinalizar (se for o caso) ou simplesmente esperar outra pessoa explicar o problema antes de negativar.

Comment: @Math Então... como o sistema pode tratar alguns casos e os moderadores podem tratar outros, fico com a sensação de que esse receio é meio infundado. Agora que o Diego falou da sensação da inimizade, compreendo esse lado, mas daí acho que também caberia à pessoa deixar pra lá-- deixar a tarefa de negativar para quem tem a paciência e o "desapego" de explicar direitinho o problema.

Comment: Em série em uma pergunta ou resposta será feito por pessoas diferentes e provavelmente serão em maioria legítimos, já downvotes em perguntas ou respostas de um usuário específico este sim acredito que podem ser removidos, claro que não vai reverter só por reverter, provavelmente o sistema deve ser inteligente pra detectar se vem de uma mesma conta ou IP (suponho). Do meu ponto de vista o problema não é perder pontos é quando alguém tenta depreciar uma resposta ou pergunta sua específica por causa de alguma birra ou por não entender que por exemplo self-answer faz parte do funcionamento do site

Comment: Então além de orientar, ajudar, resolver problemas, ainda é necessário dar "uma boa experiencia"? Um cafézinho com biscoito também?

Comment: @brasofilo Exatamente (com a exceção do cafézinho com biscoito). Esse site não é só seu ou só dos moderadores. Se uma boa experiência para você passa por cima da boa experiência do outro, talvez um site comunitário não seja ideal pra você. Além disso, dar um voto negativo e não explicar por que não ajuda em nada, não orienta em nada e não resolve problema nenhum da pessoa que recebe o voto.

Comment: @Pablo voto negativo em coisa errada resolve o problema de quem vai precisar da informação no futuro. E mesmo sem comentário, tem bastante gente que se toca e melhora a publicação. Outros ficam debatendo o negativo, o que eu acho extremamente cansativo. O único assunto que eu acho que compensa pra falar sobre negativo aqui no SOpt é como fazer os usuários novos "entrarem no clima". Quanto aos em série, já foram discutidos por aqui, e como você notou, tem mecanismos pra tratar disso (nem que seja manualmente). Eu acho legal quando possível, explicar o voto, mas tem contexto em que não adianta.

Comment: @Bacco Como voto negativo ajuda quem vai procurar depois se não tiver explicação? Se a pessoa não sabe por que a resposta é ruim, não vai passar a saber magicamente.

Comment: @Pablo se o cara achar que uma resposta com -3 é melhor que uma com 10, aí é critério dele. Primeiro, que se ele entende do assunto, já vai ver de cara que tem coisa errada, e se não entende, não vai se arriscar. E se arriscar, avisado foi. Os votos são uma das grandes diferenças que o SOpt e o resto da rede tem de diferencial. E nada melhor do que uns negativos pra pessoa pensar algumas vezes mais antes de escrever. Eu acho que quem quer procurar "comunidade" tem que ir pro Facebook, e deixar esse tipo de site aqui pra quem quer levar as postagens a sério. Aqui o que vale é o conteúdo.

Comment: @Bacco Acredito que você deveria ler o "sobre"  do Stack Exchange se acha que isso aqui não é uma comunidade. http://stackexchange.com/about

Comment: @Pablo eu acho que tem que ler tudo que o site fornece, não só um pedaço. E entender o conjunto todo. Mas aí a gente já está fugindo do foco da questão, creio eu.

Comment: Eu tenho a noite toda. :) Não vejo nada que justifique esse tipo de atitude nas diretrizes do site. Acredito que tudo o que prejudica o ambiente, especialmente para os novatos, prejudica a todos nós. Certamente as contribuições vindas de você e dos demais colegas que comentaram aqui são imensuráveis, mas não tem como medir o que já perdemos aqui por causa dessa má impressão que passamos para quem chega.

Comment: Após ler os comentários, percebi Pablo que você agora está querendo mudar a mentalidade da galera, tentando convencer a todos a justificar downvote, e isso nunca vai acontecer. Cada um tem uma visão do que faz no site, e por mais que sua questão seja razoavel, você não vai convencer a todos que devem justificar os negativos, isso é uma questão muito pessoal, e o rumo que esta discussão está tomando, está virando um paradoxo de opiniões divergentes.

Comment: Pablo, voto anônimo e sem necessidade de explicação é um fundamento que garante a qualidade da rede [se]. Tenho certeza que isso não vai mudar *nunca*,  então a turma que tem outras idéias está simplesmente perdendo tempo e lutando contra falsos problemas. No fundo, com as melhores intenções, estão querendo piorar o site.

Comment: @brasofilo concordo com isso tudo que você disse, e o mais interessante é que não foi essa mentalidade de "aceitamos qualquer coisa" que a rede virou o que é. Se a rede tivesse começado com essa mentalidade, seria um "Yahoo respostas" menos conhecido e não faria diferença. Quanto ao que o Pablo falou do que "perdemos aqui por má impressão", acho que já foram dadas soluções em outras postagens, que não envolvem mudar nada da mecânica. Como, por exemplo, deixar avisos para novatos entenderem os negativos de maneira impessoal.

Comment: @Bacco, pensando nisso, o negativo em si já é uma mensagem, um recado, um feedback... o pessoal frita tanto com "o que fiz errado?" que esquece o fundamental "o que posso fazer pra melhorar?"... bueno, ok, vão aprender da maneira mais difícil...

Comment: O complicado é que isso aqui virou uma discussão que cabe em outras perguntas, mas fugiu totalmente do post original. O que está sendo discutido nos comments já foi mais do que debatido aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/652 - aliás, estamos precisando de um novo recurso: quando tiver a palavra "negativo" no título da postagem, aparecer um quadro "tem certeza que quer entrar de novo nesse assunto? Veja [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=negativos) antes de fazer uma nova postagem sobre votos negativos" kkk

Comment: @DiegoF Estou querendo mudar a seguinte situação: Alguém me vê digitando no StackOverflow e diz: "Nossa, você tem paticipa do Stack Overflow? Pô, esses caras são todos sem educação." . Acredito que toda a nossa imagem de uma comunidade de gente que se ajuda está sendo manchada por atitudes como essas que podem ser facilmente resolvidas com um pouco de paciência e bom senso.

Comment: @Bacco Eu não tinha visto essa publicação. De qualquer forma, fiz a pergunta por que a questão da retaliação é a justificativa que mais vejo sendo usada para não justificar votos e, pelo que eu entendo, não se sustenta. Quanto a achar que os votos negativos são o que tornou a rede o que é, discordo: acredito que as sinalizações são o que possibilitaram isso. Estou aberto a demonstrações do contrário.

Comment: @brasofilo Você está mudando completamente o assunto. Eu não sou do tipo que apoia perguntas fora do escopo, respostas com links, miguxês etc. Quanto a conteúdo, se não ficou claro, eu acredito que estamos no caminho certo. O problema é quanto a _atitudades_ das pessoas aqui, especialmente com os novatos. E o site tinha vários "fundamentos" no princípio que hoje já não são bem-vindos. Dizer que uma coisa é boa só porque sempre foi assim é [apelo à tradição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_antiquitatem).

Comment: Que fique claro: não estou propondo mecanismo nenhum para coibir esse problema-- acredito que o bom senso tem que ser o suficiente para resolver essa questão, ou então somos mesmo uma comunidade muito triste. Se essa expansão do assunto aqui nos comentários servir para alguma coisa, que sirva para deixar o recado de acredito que podemos ser melhores do que isso, e sem interferência do sistema.

Comment: @Pablo, na verdade, só estou expondo que as pessoas que tem que ser convencidas sobre alguma mudança no anonimato do voto e qualquer obrigatoriedade de comentar à respeito são: os funcionários e os acionistas da empresa... good luck with that...

Comment: Se eu quisesse propor uma mudança à "tradição" começaria estudando o assunto por aqui: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+downvote+comment

Comment: No fim das contas, +1 por levantar o assunto! Ia ser legal se a gente conseguisse evoluir a conversa do -1 considerando que isso faz parte do *Business Model* do Stack Overflow. Papo emotivo não serve, se tiver uma idéia genial, vai lá e apresenta no Big Meta, depois volta com os resultados aqui :P

Comment: @brasofilo Obrigado! Desculpe se minhas ideias soaram emotivas. Certamente não foi a intenção! Só queria mesmo trazer esse assunto à tona porque é fácil esquecer, às vezes, que todos nós já fomos novatos em tudo o que somos experts. Não acho que é uma boa criar uma sugestão de melhoria no Big Meta a respeito disso: como eu disse, acredito que a solução só serve se for algo espontâneo, orgânico, sem a necessidade de ferramentas para tal. Além disso, parece que lá o problema dos novatos já é outro-- a questão do que é ou não fora de escopo é o que deixa os novatos (e muito veterano) frustrados.

Comment: Pablo, um dos caras que inventou este sistema falou "não achei que podia ser tão viciante, mas é muito viciante".  Quando estou por ai pela internet fico agoniado porque não posso fazer correções gramaticais ou de formatação. . . . Tem vezes que vale a pena tentar orientar, tem vezes que negativar e ir embora é a melhor solução. Acho que dar exemplo é o melhor que podemos fazer. O autor da pergunta tá cagando e andando, mas nossos companheiros de site vão ver essa intervenção positiva e talvez da próxima melhorem a intervenção deles, e talvez encontrem um AP disposto a aprender. Sei lá! -1!

Comment: Um dos componentes fundamentais do sucesso do Stack é o -1 anônimo e sem obrigação de explicação. Pode apostar que vai tomar uma surra ideológica se apresentar essa idéia no Metão sem uma fundamentação arretada de boa, tipo cerebral total, de gênio, muito melhor que a dos fundadores da empresa. As chances são de 99% de ser fechado como duplicata. Se eu tivesse uma idéia dessa abria meu próprio business.

Answer (score 13):

Lendo os comentários, parece que a discussão que você quer levantar é mais ampla, sobre a maneira como novos usuários podem se sentir em relação ao site. Este seu [comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4925/por-que-ter-medo-de-votos-negativos-em-s%c3%a9rie#comment17655_4925) resume bem:

> Alguém me vê digitando no StackOverflow e diz: "Nossa, você tem participado do Stack Overflow? Pô, esses caras são todos sem educação."

Na mesma discussão você citou que o bom-senso deveria ser suficiente. É verdade, não tem como discordar disso. Só que o bom-senso é uma construção coletiva, e por definição algo impreciso – cada um tem a sua própria concepção de bom-senso. Portanto, sempre vai haver algum grau de desentendimento.

Acho importante [ser respeitoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) com os novos usuários. Mas, mesmo achando que podemos melhorar quanto a isso, não acredito que tenhamos um problema sério de desrespeito aos novos usuários. O nível aqui é bem melhor do que se vê nas redes sociais e em comentários de sites de notícias e blogs. Bem melhor mesmo. Ainda bem, senão eu teria ido embora faz tempo. Então, quando dizem que somos chatos, procure relativizar. Às vezes somos chatos mesmo, mas outras vezes somos tachados assim porque a outra pessoa não quer ou não sabe dialogar.

Comment: Eu deveria ter colocado mais links e contexto na pergunta, mas queria deixá-la mais objetiva para não parecer apenas mais uma pergunta sobre votos negativos. Uma coisa que não vejo aqui é usuários com alta reputação, quando agem de forma meio rude (ou pelo menos _soam_ rudes-- todos sabemos o problema da comunicação por texto), serem repreendidos (ou "orientados a se acalmar"). Coisas mais bobas como um cara que sarcasticamente comenta "Você esqueceu de postar o código!" até coisas mais graves como um sermão inteiro no primeiro comentário... fica parecendo que somos um clube fechado.

Comment: Coisas como essa deixam uma má impressão, e a primeira impressão fica, querendo ou não. A questão dos votos negativos é um aspecto desse problema maior, mas é o problema que considero mais grave, por isso me motivei a levantar essa questão. Continuo firme na ideia de que o bom-senso deveria ser o suficiente e acho que, como uma comunidade relativamente pequena, temos tempo e oportunidade para tornar essa aqui uma experiência melhor-- uma referência os próximos contribuidores que estão chegando.

Comment: A parte boa é que uma comunidade depende muito mais dos seus bons-costumes, coletivos, do que do bom-senso individual dos seus integrantes. Apelar pro bom-senso é pouco eficiente (já que mudar a cabeça de 20k pessoas é impossível), mas criar um novo habito na comunidade é uma tarefa bem menos intragável. O que eu quero dizer é que não dá pra não ter ninguém sendo rude, mas da pra ter mais gente sendo receptiva. 1 pessoa fazendo uma boa ação já compensa.

Comment: Não é questão de boa ação nem de hábito, é de civilidade. Concordo que dá pra ter mais gente sendo receptiva, esse é o caminho. Eu vi esse assunto aparecer aqui e em outros metas várias vezes, e sempre fica uma impressão de que se espera algum tipo de intervenção externa que resolva o problema. Não sei se é esse o seu caso, @Pablo, mas não existe solução assim. A solução é contrabalançar deixando comentários que auxiliam os novos usuários. Que indiquem caminhos para que ele consiga solucionar sua dúvida **e** a fazer postagens relevantes no site. E se vir algo agressivo, sinalize.

Comment: Fica todo mundo **babando** pra ter seu problema resolvido no [so]. Se os voluntários que frequentam o local fazem -1 por algum motivo ***objetivo*** já são tachados  de "sem educação". Ok, então vai lá no Yahoo pra ver que resposta você consegue. . . . . . É muito legal que haja meta discussões deste tipo, é genial esta disposição que os meta frequentadores tem de ajudar e de melhorar a interação com quem está chegando agora. Se posso ajudar, ajudo (editando ou comentando), se não, é minha prerrogativa ser sem educação e votar -1 sem dizer nada, boa sorte, tente melhorar da próxima vez.

Comment: @brasofilo A ideia de que é o -1 que nos separa do Y! Respostas é uma falsa dicotomia sem tamanho

Comment: Acho que ele não quis dizer isso, @Gabe. Até porque o Y!A também tem -1.

Comment: @bfavaretto Verdade. Mas essa não é a única coisa que discordo no comentário...

Comment: @Gabe, não, o profissionalismo na moderação do conteúdo é o que nos separa do Y! Choramingar porque tomou -1 sem nem sequer se olhar no espelho pra ver qual pode ser "seu" próprio o problema é coisa típica. Botar a culpa toda no -1 "descerebrado" também é coisa típica. Eu barbarizo aqui no Meta mas aprendi a ter uma paciência infinita no site principal. Sei lá, até hoje nunca recebi uma notificação privada dos moderadores por falta de respeito ou jogo sujo...

Comment: @Gabe, qual é exatamente a discordância? De editar conteúdos problemáticos? De fazer intervenções que o site permite e encoraja? Ou de fazer apologia do -1 no Meta?

Answer (score 10):

Existem diferentes tipos de série. Dois exemplos são:

1. Usuário `A` fica enfezado com usuário `B` e vota contra várias perguntas e respostas dele.
   Se ele fizer isso num intervalo de tempo relativamente curto, o sistema reverte automaticamente.
   Por outro lado, se ele for "cauteloso" e votar sistematicamente, pode ser que ele burle a reversão automática, embora o sistema ainda colete estatísticas que mostram tendências de votos, cabendo então a ação dos moderadores.
2. Usuário `A` faz um comentário negativo ou vota contra o conteúdo do usuário `B`; os usuários `C`, `D` e `E`, por alguma razão, são levados a imitar ou corroborar com o comportamento de `A` e também votam contra `B`. O sistema, até onde me consta, não tem e nem deve ter algum tipo de mecanismo para reverter esse esse comportamento, pois não há como diferenciar voto em bando de vários usuários legitimamente considerando um conteúdo ruim.

A maior parte dos problemas ocorre no segundo caso e há várias situações envolvidas.

Algumas pessoas são mais críticas que as outras. Tudo bem até aí. No começo do SOpt eu levei alguns negativos onde a justificativa era: *esta não é a melhor abordagem* ou *na versão XYZ da tecnologia tem um jeito melhor de fazer isso*.

Enfim, não concordo, mas se alguém acha que vale negativar tudo que não for **a** melhor abordagem, ela tem o direito dela.

O problema começa quando as pessoas veem um `-1` ali do lado e, sem nem ao menos julgar por si mesmas, sentem uma coceira para clicar no triângulo logo abaixo do número.

O impacto disso depende de quem recebe um negativo. Algumas pessoas nem ligam, outras reagem com raiva e podem até deixar o site (ou pelo menos ameaçam).

Mas o que me preocupa mais é quando um usuário faz sua primeira pergunta como `user0098761` e, antes mesmo dele ter tempo de colocar a foto dele no perfil, a pergunta já tem `-3`, votos para fechar e, com sorte, dois ou três comentários dizendo que ele precisa melhorar, quando não comentários sarcásticos ou dizendo que ele precisa estudar, aprender a escrever, fazer um curso de ciências da computação e por aí vai.

Eu lecionei desenvolvimento web com Java durante dois semestres para turmas de faculdades públicas e particulares. Eu sempre recomendei aos alunos fazerem perguntas aqui e até mesmo respondi algumas delas. Mas foi muito triste ouvir algumas vezes que *aquele pessoal é muito chato*.

Por um lado, eu sei que as perguntas deles não eram boas, por outro lado, eu fico pensando em como nós ficamos orgulhosos depois de alguns anos trabalhando e esquecemos de como é não saber nem criar um método `main` sem copiar de algum lugar.

Concluindo, eu tenho medo de negativos, porque **em alguns casos** eles reforçam uma cultura de autoproteção e manutenção de "panelinhas", onde o novato não tem chance perante o ego de um profissional com décadas de experiência, onde todos precisam ser (ou parecer) bastante conhecedores do assunto.

Comment: Só pra complementar, tem o voto negativo em série pelo simples fato do autor postar muita porcaria também. Certa vez eu tenho uma "forte impressão" que tomei uma reversão por acaso, o autor foi postando porcaria em seguida, pra terceirizar o serviço pro SOpt, mas eu nao parei pra me preocupar em ver de quem era a postagem, e fui negativando. Mais tarde, fui ver o que aconteceu com a postagem (coisa que tem salvação eu costumo por nos bookmarks pra verificar depois se melhorou), e não tinha negativo.

Comment: @Bacco, preciso localizar bookmark, mas um dos devs/empregados do Stack falou algo do gênero: "de repente, veio uma maré de empresas de apps tentando escrever suas Android Apps a base de perguntas vampíricas no Stack Overflow". Se tem um menino do interior de Rondônia aprendendo programação, vou até responder de forma "serial", o sistema não vai me punir por isso. Agora, pro resto, primeiro demonstra que não é vampiro, depois te ajudo. -1 é minha prerrogativa fundamental.

Answer (score 10):

<sup>Obs: o uso que faço do "você" é genérico, não se refere ao Autor da Pergunta</sup>

> Por que ter medo de votos negativos em série?

Não há motivo nenhum pra ter esse tipo de medo. Existe um script automático que previne esse tipo de coisa: [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting).

Se alguém eventualmente decidir que não gosta de você e que vai estudar e planejar uma maneira de fazer -1 sem que o sistema detecte, bom, isso significa que é uma pessoa que está atravessando um momento problemático ou uma vida problemática... não tem nada a ver com você...

O @Luiz toca no ponto "voto de manada" que, com certeza, é um tipo de voto em série que parece ser meio difícil de controlar. Quando vejo isso acontecer e se acho que posso fazer uma intervenção positiva, o que faço nas perguntas é:

- comentar explicando "Olha só, talvez os votos negativos sejam por ISTO e AQUILO"... a tentativa aqui é fazer o comentário o mais construtivo possível para que a pessoa possa **melhorar** sua pergunta; **não é só** "leia a central de ajuda", **é** "falta tal e tal coisa na sua pergunta";
- editar o título pra converter aquela porcaria de "Problema em PHP" em algo significativo e representante do problema apresentado, p.ex., "Erro de comunicação ao fazer um loop para o Banco de Dados"....
- editar o conteúdo para converter aquele Português meio quebrado em algo legível e formatar texto e código o melhor possível pra facilitar a leitura;
- incorporar comentários explicativos do AP no corpo da pergunta;
- acertar as tags se necessário.

Pensando aqui, acho que nunca vi "voto de manada" problemático numa resposta... (sejamos sinceros, fica todo mundo "my precious, my precious" com seus pontos e poucos se dispõe a pagar -1 por negativar uma resposta). Se a resposta levou mais de um negativo, provavelmente merece, e são grandes as chances de que alguém teve coragem de explicar o problema num comentário.

Fazer critica objetiva e profissional não é ofensa. Se a outra pessoa não está preparada, azar dela.

Fazer click no -1 **já é uma mensagem** e tem um objetivo definido na Interface do Usuário: "seu post tem um problema, favor verificar". Entrar em pane e ter um finiquito não ajudam em nada. Você postou algo num site público, uma outra pessoa achou ruim; vai lá e confere as regras do site pra saber o que pode melhorar. Alguém te deu um toque que pode ajudar nisso? Leu o conselho com atenção?

Tudo bem, você é novato, mas está a fim de se mover entre profissionais?
A chance de aprender aqui é muito grande, de melhorar como profissional, de terminar escrevendo como se fosse um redator de revista, levar um -1 aqui ou pagar um -1 ali é um preço muito pequeno.

Comment: Eu concordo com todos os seus pontos, mas discordo da "frequências e chances" dos comentários ou downvotes. Eles não são raros, e as chances de comentários não são grandes. E é só por isso que eu acho que discussões como essas (e respostas como essa) valem muito à pena.

Comment: che, Gabe, li e reli, mas não vejo "frequencias e chances" no meu texto... É sobre o negativo em respostas?

Comment: Se for em respostas, minha avaliação é puramente empirica, mas, nossa, super dificil ver -1 em manada numa resposta (não sei no SOpt, pq não ando acompanhando de perto, mas no esquema SE, poucas vezes vi -1 em manada pra respostas)